# HIGHDPIAWARE for all apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, regedit, high-dpi

I'm using Windows 10 and currently, I specifically set for each app, the [*HIGHDPIAWARE*](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-adjust-high-dpi-scaling-in-windows-10/) (high-DPI scaling) attribute in registry key which is found in :

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

With these values :

[image]

But I really don't want to specify each app for that feature.

**Question:**

How can I make all apps to be `HIGHDPIAWARE`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Old applications cannot be made high-dpi aware without any changes, because that needs the app to use the newer high-dpi APIs. Apps must declare themselves as high-dpi aware via a manifest file or some API calls, otherwise Windows will scale them bitmap-wise which makes them blurry. That's what the above registry key is about. The detail settings are like this

> - HIGHDPIAWARE: Disable Display Scaling on High DPI Settings - Scaling performed by: Application (Win7/10)
> - DPIUNAWARE: Scaling performed by: Application (Win10 build 15002+)
> - GDIDPISCALING DPIUNAWARE: Scaling performed by: System (Enhanced) (Win10 build 15002+)
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-compatibility.html

In fact that key is exactly the same as the dpi-override settings in compatibility tab if you open the *.exe file's properties

So setting HIGHDPIAWARE in ...\AppCompatFlags\Layers doesn't automatically make your app hi-dpi aware. It just makes Windows *thinks* that the app is hi-dpi aware and [disable scaling](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/11/21/disabling-dpi-scaling-on-windows-8-1-the-enterprise-way/). The app is shown at 100% scaling so it'll be smaller on high-dpi displays, but the result is sharper

Of course you can [set the flag for multiple apps at once](https://superuser.com/q/1230346/241386), but it's not the way to solve your issue. Overriding high-dpi settings for all apps may make real high-dpi aware apps misbehave

See also

- [How to force high-dpi scaling?](https://superuser.com/q/127214/241386)
- [What does "Disable Display Scaling on High DPI Settings" on Windows 10 mean?](https://superuser.com/q/1100491/241386)
- [Windows scaling issues for high-DPI devices](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025083/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices)
- [How to make the Windows Desktop application work well on High-DPI Displays and Fix Blurry Fonts](http://komalmangal.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-make-windows-desktop-work-well.html)

Comment: @Stefan the question is "How can I make all apps to be HIGHDPIAWARE?" and the answer is **you can't** without modifying the source code of the application. If you have any questions kindly post a different one. But if you want to show all apps at 100% then there's no scaling being applied. If you just want to show an app at 100% then it's absolutely irrelevant to making the app hidpi aware, it still has no idea of hidpi displays and is just being rendered at 100% dpi

Comment: The question is how to make programs "`HIGHDPIAWARE`", not "high-DPI aware". Enabling that flag tells Windows to not automatically scale the program (making it blurry), even if it's not actually DPI-aware. Enabling it for all programs (by setting a global environment variable) disables automatic scaling for non-DPI aware programs, but DPI-aware programs are unaffected.